# C#. En un proyecto C# no me permite utilizar 'using System.Device.Location;'

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

en primer lugar gracias y comentar que soy nuevo en el tema, por lo que la pregunta probablemente será básica.

En un proyecto C# Forms, intento añadir mediante 'using' la API 'System.Device.Location'.
Tengo instalada la versión 4.8 de Microsoft .Net Framework y en teória, creo que debería aparecer en la lista.

La pregunta es: ¿qué se debe hacer para disponer de esos componentes que no aparecen en el desplegable al codificar 'Using System......'?

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 4):

El namespace `System.Device.Location` pertenece al assembly `System.Device.dll` que por defecto no es añadido como referencia a los proyectos Windows Forms.

Así que lo que tienes que hacer es, primero agregar la referencia a ese assembly y luego podrás añadir la directiva using `System.Device.Location`.

1. Agregar el assembly como referencia al proyecto.

En el Solution Explorer haz click derecho en el nodo **References** del proyecto y selecciona **Add Reference...** como en la imagen siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En el cuadro de diálogo que aparece (Reference Manager) asegúrate de expandir Assemblies y en la caja de texto arriba a la derecha escribe `System.Device` y presiona enter. Cuando aparezca el assembly como resultado marca el checkbox y presiona el botón **OK**. Mira la imagen siguiente:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez hecho esto, puedes agregar el using `System.Device.Location`.

Comment: Perfecto!. Así lo he hecho y ha funcionado. Muchisimas gracias, Karel! Un saludo